# 2 problems putting Like button on my website

Tags: php, facebook-like

I am the PHP developer for a website, and recently replaced the Sharer.php code with the newer code examples. The Like button displays properly, but when you click on it, the pop-up displays for only a second or two, then disappears. Also, the description isn't showing up in the pop-up - just the URL. The Like button code is contained within a DIV container that can be hidden by the user (using JQuery), and there is AJAX on the page to automatically query a table once a minute to refresh an on-screen counter.

Here are some code snippets in case they help, and any help is appreciated:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="FourFreedomsBlog - Romney/Ryan: Channeling the  inner McCain" />
<meta property="og:description" content="The Romney/Ryan campaign is evoking an eerie recollection of the McCain campaign of 2008: trust us - you'll get the details AFTER we're elected." />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.fourfreedomsblog.com/Blog.php?Act=ViewBlogPost&amp;BlogID=2090" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.FourFreedomsBlog.com/images/4Fv3.0.gif" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="FourFreedoms Blog" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="14194340826" />

<div class="ShareThisContainer">

<div class="FoldingMenu">
  <h4><button id="showShareThis" class="ButtonHide" /></button><span name="" id="">Share This!</span></h4>

  <div id="SharePane" class="TogPane ItemHide">

    <table class="ShareThis">
      <tr>
        <td colspan=8>

          <div id="fb-root"></div>

          <script>
            (function(d, s, id) {
              var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];

              if (d.getElementById(id)) return;

              js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
              js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
              fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }
            (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
          </script>

          <div class="fb-like" data-href="http%3A%2F%2Fwww.FourFreedomsBlog.com%2FBlog.php?Act=ViewBlogPost&BlogID=2090" data-send="true" data-width="320" data-show-faces="true"></div>

        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div><!-- id=SharePane -->

</div><!-- class=FoldingMenu -->
</div><!-- class=ShareThisContainer -->
```

Answer (score 0):

> `<div class="fb-like" data-href="http%3A%2F%2Fwww.FourFreedomsBlog.com%2FBlog.php?Act=ViewBlogPost&BlogID=2090" …`

First of all, *do not* URL-encode the value of the `data-href` parameter here.

Second of all, *do not* use upper-case letters in your domain name – the Facebook scraper fails on domain names with upper case letters – compare

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.FourFreedomsBlog.com%2FBlog.php%3FAct%3DViewBlogPost%26BlogID%3D2090

vs

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fourfreedomsblog.com%2FBlog.php%3FAct%3DViewBlogPost%26BlogID%3D2090

And then, finally, fix the error the debug tool shows:

> Object Invalid Value: Object at URL 'http://www.fourfreedomsblog.com/Blog.php?Act=ViewBlogPost&BlogID=2090' of type 'website' is invalid because the given value '14194340826' for property 'fb:admins' could not be parsed as type 'fbid'.

14194340826 is the id of a Facebook *group* – but groups can not be “administrators” of anything, just normal user accounts can be.

Comment: good catches - thanks. And I will bookmark that debug link for future use.